# inserting object in a map without copying the object

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Is it possible to insert objects in a map, if the class of the object has disabled copy constructor and disabled copy operator? Is move semantics useful here?

```
#include <map>

class T {
public:
  T(int v): x(v) {};
private:
  T(const T &other); // disabled!
  T &operator=(const T &other); // disabled!
  int x;
};

int main() {
  std::map<int, T> m;
  m[42] = T(24);  // compilation error here!
}
```

**edit** I was not completely clear. The object is huge, so I don't want to make unnecessary copies of it. But I can modify the code of the class (maybe I need to implement move semantics?) and not the user code (the main function in the example).

Comment: Note also that `m[42]` requires `T` default constructor too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
class T {
public:
  T(){};
  T(int v): x(v) {};
  T(const T &other) = delete;
  T(T&& other) {x = other.x; std::cout << "move ctor\n";}
  T &operator=(const T &other) = delete;
  T& operator=(T&& other) {x = other.x; std::cout << "move assigment\n";}
 private:
  int x;
};

int main() {
  std::map<int, T> m;
  m.insert(std::make_pair(42, T(24))); 
  m[44] = T(25);
}
```

Comment: I think this is my preferred solution... waiting for possible comments before accepting

Answer (score 4):

Use emplacement syntax:

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(42), std::forward_as_tuple(24));
//                              ^^                         ^^
//                            int(42)                     T(24)
```

Or, in C++17, use `try_emplace`:

```
m.try_emplace(42, 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might insert as pointer:

```
public:
    T(int v) : x(v) {};
    int getX(){ return this->x; }
private:
    T(const T &other); // disabled!
    T &operator=(const T &other); // disabled!
    int x;
};

int main() 
{
    std::map<int, T*> m;

    m[42] = new T(24);  // no compilation error here!

    std::cout << m[42]->getX() << std::endl; // prints out 24

    return 0;
}
```